# mod of an unsigned char from secure hash function

Tags: char, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword, unsigned, modulo

i have an unsigned char test_SHA1[20] of 20 bytes which is a return value from a hash function. With the following code, I get this output

```
unsigned char test_SHA1[20];
char hex_output[41];
for(int di = 0; di < 20; di++)
{
    sprintf(hex_output + di*2, "%02x", test_SHA1[di]);
}

printf("SHA1 = %s\n", hex_output);
```

50b9e78177f37e3c747f67abcc8af36a44f218f5

The last 9 bits of this number is 0x0f5 (= 245 in decimal) which I would get by taking a mod 512 of test_SHA1. To take mod 512 of test_SHA1, I do

```
int x = (unsigned int)test_SHA1 % 512;
printf("x = %d\n", x);
```

But x turns out to be 158 instead of 245.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing a bit-wise and with 0x1ff instead of using the `%` operator.

Comment: thanks. i tried "test_SHA1 = test_SHA1 & 0x1ff;" but it is giving me a compile error. could you pls post the command to do the bitwise AND and convert that into decimal.

Comment: I just realized that test_SHA1 is an array (20 long, I'm assuming from your loop). Assuming it's an array of char, you should use `(test_SHA1[18] & 1) + test_SHA1[19]`. Or if it's a wider integer type, `test_SHA1[19] & 0x1ff`. This also explains the earlier result--you were casting an array pointer (an address) to an unsigned int and taking the lower 9 bits of the address.

Comment: my mistake. i should have added the declaration for test_SHA1. I edited the post to add it.

Comment: @Ted Hopp with test_SHA1 an unsigned char of 20bytes, could you pls post how to change this code "int x = (unsigned int)test_SHA1 % 512;" to get x = 245.

Comment: Try `int x = (test_SHA1[18] & 1) + (unsigned int)(test_SHA1[19])`.

Comment: Thanks very much! That worked. Just an observation, just by removing the braces around "test_SHA1[18] & 1", it is giving an incorrect result. It might be due to some operator precedence.